# Running crysis 2 on ubuntu gives me an error message

Tags: wine, games, hybrid-graphics

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside windows 7 and i installed `crysis 2` with `wine`. crysis 2 works fine when i run windows, however when i run it using wine in Ubuntu cryengine gives me a message saying:

> Unsupported video card detected! Continuing to run migth lead to unexpected results or crashes.....

I've got two video cards ones an Intel and the other is a Nvidia. I typed `lspci` into the terminal and my Nvidia card was listed under video controller as well.

Comment: What graphics card model are you using? Is it mobile version or Desktop card?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using nVidia's so-called "optimus" technology, their solution to hybrid graphics.

If that's indeed the case, you should notice Linux has no native way to deal with these hybrid graphics. Your system will leave both adapters powered on while using one (generally your Intel integrated graphics), which is most probably the reason why you see such a message when trying to run an intensive 3D application.

In order to be able to correctly "switch" to the right adapter, you will need a special application like Bumblebee. In a nutshell, installation is as simple as the following 3 lines (after which a reboot will be needed):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

However, before proceeding, I recommend you to take a look at the Bumblebee site for more information: http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html.

Once bumblebee is installed, your system will keep using your intel graphics by default, but you'll be able to run an application using your dedicated nvidia card with the following command:

```
optirun <yourapplication>
```

In your case, you want to run Crysis, which is loaded through wine. The command will look like this (assuming you're in the Crysis2 directory):

```
optirun wine crysis2.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

- Is Wine using the Nvidia card?
- If so, do you have the drivers for Nvidia installed in Ubuntu?
- Did you install DirectX on the prefix your using for Wine?

Try verifying all the points I've mentioned and start from a clean wine prefix.

After guaranteeing that Wine/Ubuntu are using the Nvidia card, install the Nvidia drivers for Ubuntu. Then:

```
cd $HOME
mkdir crysis2
WINEPREFIX="/home/USERNAME/crysis2" winecfg
```

Change USERNAME to the user name, that is logged in.

Run `winetricks` to install Directx.

Check http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25331 for further assistance. It is classified as Gold for Crysis 2 v1.9 using Wine 1.5.3.

Good luck! :)